# Как понять откуда к div блоку добавляется style?

Tags: jquery

Вообщем в opera есть такая замечательная штуковина как dragonfly ( очень полезная вещь для верстальщика, я всегда могу узнать какой стиль влияет на блок, узнать вплоть до строки в документе ) Мне интересно, можно также легко узнать откуда добавляется, допустим, к блоку .css через jquery?

Comment: Откуда пишется так — откуда.

Comment: Пишется пишется так - пишется, ты об этом?

Comment: У меня все отлично с интелектом, я пришел не совета по русскому языку спросить, а на QA it ресурс.

Comment: Вот именно потому, что вы пришли на QA ресурс, нужно писать на чистом русском языке, а не на языке школьника средних классов.

Comment: Stanislaw Pankevich "на чистом русском языке" попахивает расизмом. Т.е вы утверждаете что QA сервисы только для русских? Так а теперь без шуток!!! укажите хотябы на одну грамотическую ошибку в моём сообщение!!!
Вы обкурились чтоли все в раз???? "Откуда пишется так — откуда" у человека похоже уже мозг протикает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это узнать нельзя. (Можно, конечно, поставить на паузу выполнение Яваскриптов и мануально жмакать на кнопочки и смотреть по шагам выполнение скриптов и видеть, что там происходит. В Хроме это вкладочка «Sources»).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как в Опере, но в Chrome и FF можно поставить "Break on attributes modifications" на нужном элементе и отследить какой код меняет аттрибуты.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Определить к какому классу пренадлежит этот блок, и искать этот класс во всех стилях, если класса нет, то тег.

Comment: Угу, это понятно. Я имел в виду удобный, альтернативный вариант. Просто я пару лет назат мучался со стилями без dragonfly незная о нем.